# Set more than 2 values depends on conditions, python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
        Nickname      Vpip%       Pfr%       Agg  Hands
0       -2dV2dA-  25.675676  16.666667  1.187500    222
1        06Hookd  26.470588  16.176471  1.000000     68
2     0spiel2632  23.794212  17.363344  0.750000    311
3        10Pet10  23.214286   7.142857  1.000000     56
4      12022015a  75.000000        NaN       NaN      4
5      17bastian  31.034483   6.896552  1.000000     29
6      1990shawn  26.666667   6.666667  0.500000     15
7      199376966  66.666667  25.000000  1.000000     12
8     1MILKSHAKE  75.000000  50.000000       NaN      4
9    1nheritance  30.136986  20.547945  1.000000     73
10      2016deal  63.076923  12.307692  1.142857     65
11        26tj26  43.589744  30.769231  1.333333     39
12     2SMUG4YOU  70.000000  20.000000  1.000000     10
13          320t  71.074380  38.842975  1.410256    121
14    4cheeze126  52.205882  34.926471  0.900000    272
15      67bishop  19.148936   2.127660  1.000000     47
16    777aprilia  23.076923  15.384615       NaN     13
17   77gost77129  17.241379  14.942529       NaN     87
18         7r3m5  19.942197  16.473988  1.111111    346
19  888sharkbait  50.000000  30.769231  0.750000     26
```

I want to make one more column depends on values.
I'm using np.where to set values but it can only set 2 values depends on condition.
I need to put many values.
I tried to do it with np.where but it replacing each other.

```
Data['Badge'] = np.where((Data['Hands'] > 30) & (Data['Vpip%'] <= 18.0), 'Rock', np.nan)
Data['Badge'] = np.where((Data['Hands'] > 30) & (Data['Vpip%'] > 60.0), 'Whale', np.nan)
Data['Badge'] = np.where((Data['Hands'] > 30) & (Data['Vpip%'] <= 60.0) & ((Data['Vpip%'] > 40.0)), 'Fish', np.nan)
Data['Badge'] = np.where((Data['Hands'] > 30) & (Data['Vpip%'] <= 40.0) & ((Data['Vpip%'] > 27.0) & (Data['Agg'] < 2.0)), 'Loose Passive', np.nan)
Data['Badge'] = np.where((Data['Hands'] > 30) & (Data['Vpip%'] <= 40.0) & ((Data['Vpip%'] > 27.0) & (Data['Agg'] > 2.0)), 'Loose Aggresive', np.nan)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For multiple conditions use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) instead:

```
c1 = (Data['Hands'] > 30) & (Data['Vpip%'] <= 18.0)
c2 = (Data['Hands'] > 30) & (Data['Vpip%'] > 60.0)
c3 = (Data['Hands'] > 30) & (Data['Vpip%'] <= 60.0)
c4 = ((Data['Hands'] > 30) & (Data['Vpip%'] <= 40.0) 
      & ((Data['Vpip%'] > 27.0) & (Data['Agg'] < 2.0)))
c5 = ((Data['Hands'] > 30) & (Data['Vpip%'] <= 40.0) 
      & ((Data['Vpip%'] > 27.0) & (Data['Agg'] > 2.0)))

Data['Badge'] = (np.select(condlist = [c1,c2,c3,c4,c5], 
                           choicelist = ['Rock', 'Whale', 'Fish', 'Loose Passive', 
                                         'Loose Aggresive'], 
                           default = np.nan))
```

---

```
print(Data)

Nickname      Vpip%       Pfr%       Agg  Hands  Badge
0       -2dV2dA-  25.675676  16.666667  1.187500    222   Fish
1        06Hookd  26.470588  16.176471  1.000000     68   Fish
2     0spiel2632  23.794212  17.363344  0.750000    311   Fish
3        10Pet10  23.214286   7.142857  1.000000     56   Fish
4      12022015a  75.000000        NaN       NaN      4    nan
5      17bastian  31.034483   6.896552  1.000000     29    nan
6      1990shawn  26.666667   6.666667  0.500000     15    nan
7      199376966  66.666667  25.000000  1.000000     12    nan
8     1MILKSHAKE  75.000000  50.000000       NaN      4    nan
9    1nheritance  30.136986  20.547945  1.000000     73   Fish
10      2016deal  63.076923  12.307692  1.142857     65  Whale
11        26tj26  43.589744  30.769231  1.333333     39   Fish
12     2SMUG4YOU  70.000000  20.000000  1.000000     10    nan
13          320t  71.074380  38.842975  1.410256    121  Whale
14    4cheeze126  52.205882  34.926471  0.900000    272   Fish
15      67bishop  19.148936   2.127660  1.000000     47   Fish
16    777aprilia  23.076923  15.384615       NaN     13    nan
17   77gost77129  17.241379  14.942529       NaN     87   Rock
18         7r3m5  19.942197  16.473988  1.111111    346   Fish
19  888sharkbait  50.000000  30.769231  0.750000     26    nan
```